# IA32 Assembly Language Read integers from file

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I am trying to read integers from a file and then output them to a new file. I guess where I am most confused is when reading in the integers. Please take a look at my code and by the way I am just a beginner with assembly language.

```
.data
filename:
.asciz "indata.txt"
out:
.asciz "outdata.txt"
.bss
.lcomm num, 5
.lcomm filehandle, 4
.text
.globl _start
_start:

# Open input file
movl $5, %eax #open file
movl $filename, %ebx #filename
movl $00, %ecx #rd
movl $0444, %edx
int $0x80
test %eax, %eax #Test
js badfile
movl %eax, filehandle

# Open output file
movl $5, %eax
movl $out, %ebx
movl $01101, %ecx
movl $0644, %edx
int $0x80
test %eax, %eax
js badfile
movl %eax, out

readloop:
#Read and store input.
movl $3, %eax #Read
movl filehandle, %ebx   
movl $num, %ecx #memory adress of input string
movl $5, %edx #length
int $0x80       
test %eax, %eax #Test
jz done
js badfile
movl %eax, %edx

#Convert to number
subl $48, num


# Write output to file
movl $4, %eax
movl out, %ebx
movl $num, %ecx
int $0x80
test %eax,%eax
js badfile
jmp readloop

badfile:
movl %eax, %ebx
movl $1, %eax
int $0x80

done:

#Close file.
movl $6, %eax
movl filehandle, %ebx
int $0x80

#Close file.
movl $6, %eax
movl out, %ebx
int $0x80

movl $1, %eax
movl $0, %ebx
int $0x80
```

Comment: Where is it failing, and what does your file contain? I just want to be sure the file contains "raw" binary data, rather than ASCII text.

Comment: The output includes a box with numbers in it. Im assuming thats "raw" data, Also it includes a few numbers and even a '\0'.

Comment: Is there a way to read line by line, ignoring the new line char, rather than a specified number of bytes? I believe what is causing the error is that if I read '1' it will read that along with a new line char and bytes from the next line as well.

Comment: That sounds like ASCII to me - your code even says as much, that is why it subtracts 48 from the input to get the actual number.

Comment: I suspect that you are hitting a value in the file that is isn't a valid ASCII number (google ASCII table), and it's exiting early. You'll need to compare the character you have read with any "special" values (such as \0, which is actually zero), and jump back to the beginning of the readloop if it matches. If in doubt, use a hex editor to see what the file contents really looks like. Just relying on Notepad will really trip you up.

Comment: Thanks! The hex editor was very helpful.

Comment: NO worries, feel free to hand out some upvotes!